# Left and Right Ideal Generated by Two Matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R= {\rm Mat}_2(\Bbb R)$ be the ring (with $1$) of $2\times2$-matrices with entries in $\Bbb R$. Let $$M = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$ i.e. a set of two matrices. What are the left and right ideal generated by $M$ in $R$?

---

I tried to write my answer by it won't accept it. I don't know how to write Matrices (and their product) in the right format.

Is this correct: 
For left ideal: $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\c&0\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&c\end{pmatrix}$$

hence $L = \begin{pmatrix}a&a\\c&c\end{pmatrix}$.

For right ideal:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

hence $R = \begin{pmatrix}a+c&b+d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Is this correct:

For left ideal: (a,b;c,d)*(1,0;0,0)=(a,0;c,0) and (a,b;c,d)(0,1;0,0)=(0,a;0,c)

=> L=(a,a;c,c)

For right ideal: (1,0;0,0)*(a,b;c,d)=(a,b;0,0) and (0,1;0,0)(a,b;c,d)=(c,d;0,0)

=> R=(a+c,b+d;0,0)

Comment: I tried my best to write the question. The things in (.) are supposed to be 2x2 matrices. How do I write matrices here? Can a mod please edit my question?

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: I have edited the question for you. I hope to not have made any transcription errors.

Comment: Yeah everything is correct now. Thanks much. Do you know if my results are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there are some issues here caused by your choice of notation. By multiplying the same $a,b,c,d$ matrix with both generators, you've overlooked that there's nothing wrong with multiplying the generators with *two different* matrices and adding, which will produce many more possiblities.

In the left ideal generated by those two things, a general element will look like this:

$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&e\\c&g\end{bmatrix}$.

Notice how we didn't recycle the $a,b,c,d$ matrix for *both* generators. Since you can pick $a,e,c,g$ to be whatever you want, you can see that the left ideal generated by these two things is the *entire* matrix ring.

Try to apply similar reasoning to the right ideal generated by these two things. You will get a different answer than the left ideal, and the answer you gave is not incorrect. It's just that you can express what the right ideal looks like more simply.

Comment: Isn't the right ideal $\begin{bmatrix}a+g&b+h\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ then? How can I make it simpler?

Comment: @blondy Yes, that's all correct: everything in the right ideal can be written that way. But, after you've realized this, you can reexpress what the ideal looks like without $+$ signs, and even without talking about $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$. Can you see how? I just want you to focus on *which matrices are in the right ideal* rather than the detailed analysis we just did.

Comment: @blondy Your answer would fill in this blank to answer this question: "Q: Which matrices are in the right ideal generated by these?" A: "The ones with ___________." (No references to $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ would be even needed, actually :) ).

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}i&j\\0&0\end{bmatrix} ???

Comment: @blondy Yes, that is 99% what I was guiding you towards :) I was hoping for "matrices with zeros in the bottom row." Good job!